# How to get GMSPlace for a CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a location coordinate in the form of a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. How do I get its equivalent GMSPlace object using the Google Maps SDK?

This seems like it should be a very simple task, but I couldn't find anything in Google's documentation or on Stack Overflow.

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I am working on a similar issue, and I haven't found the exact solution but these alternatives may work depending on your situation. If you are okay with having a `GMSAddress` instead of a `GMSPlace`, you may use a [GMSGeocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder) with a call to `reverseGeocodeCoordinate` as seen in option two below.

Two options if you're trying to get the user's current location:

1. **Use Google Maps current location to get a GMSPlace.** This is pretty simple and solves your problem if you are okay with only resorting to actual places. The problem with this is that I couldn't figure out how to get all addresses (as opposed to businesses). You can see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place).

   In viewDidLoad:

   ```
   let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
   ```

   When you want to get the current place:

   ```
   placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
     if error != nil {
       // Handle error in some way.
     }

     if let placeLikelihood = placeLikelihoods?.likelihoods.first {
       let place = placeLikelihood.place
       // Do what you want with the returned GMSPlace.
     }
   })
   ```
2. **Use [OneShotLocationManager](https://github.com/icanzilb/OneShotLocationManager/blob/master/OneShotLocationManager.swift) to get the CLLocationCoordinate2D and turn it into a GMSAddress.** You will have to replace the `_didComplete` function with the code below to return a GMSAddress instead of a CLLocationCoordinate2D.

   ```
   private func _didComplete(location: CLLocation?, error: NSError?) {
     locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()

     if let location = location {
       GMSGeocoder().reverseGeocodeCoordinate(location.coordinate, completionHandler: {
       [unowned self] (response, error) -> Void in
       if error != nil || response == nil || response!.firstResult() == nil {
         self.didComplete?(location: nil,
                           error: NSError(domain: self.classForCoder.description(),
                           code: LocationManagerErrors.InvalidLocation.rawValue,
                           userInfo: nil))
        } else {
          self.didComplete?(location: response!.firstResult(), error: error)
        }
        })
     } else {
       self.didComplete?(location: nil, error: error)
     }

     locationManager?.delegate = nil
     locationManager = nil
   }
   ```

Someone posted on [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8121) a convenient wrapper to extract fields from the `GMSAddressComponents` that you may find useful when dealing with this API. This makes it easy because then when you want to access the city all you have to do is `place.addressComponents?.city` as an example.

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == GMSAddressComponent {
  var streetAddress: String? {
      return "\(valueForKey("street_number")) \(valueForKey(kGMSPlaceTypeRoute))"
  }

  var city: String? {
      return valueForKey(kGMSPlaceTypeLocality)
  }

  var state: String? {
      return valueForKey(kGMSPlaceTypeAdministrativeAreaLevel1)
  }

  var zipCode: String? {
      return valueForKey(kGMSPlaceTypePostalCode)
  }

  var country: String? {
      return valueForKey(kGMSPlaceTypeCountry)
  }

  func valueForKey(key: String) -> String? {
      return filter { $0.type == key }.first?.name
  }
}
```

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. It seems that GMSPlaces (Google Places) and GMSAddress (Google Maps) are objects from separate APIs and are thus not easily compatible. Sort of weird considering they both basically deal with Google Maps. An annoying (alternative) solution is creating your own custom "place object" and setting its properties to those you desire from both the GMSAddress object and the GMSPlace object.